# Why does route creation fail for StatefulWidget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a route with a StatefulWidget.

**Error:**

```
I/flutter (23141): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (23141): The following assertion was thrown building
I/flutter (23141): _OverlayEntry-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryState>#3e9ee](dirty, state: _OverlayEntryState#7b90c):
I/flutter (23141): The builder for route "/" returned null.
I/flutter (23141): Route builders must never return null.
```

**Code:**

```
routes:<String,WidgetBuilder>{
        "/":(_)=>new RouteHome(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        ...
```

```js
class RouteHome extends StatefulWidget {
  RouteHome({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}
```

**Queries:**

- Why would it not be allowed for a StatefulWidget?

---

**Issue:**
Hot reload fails for routes if the widget's base class is changed (StatefulWidget <-> StatelessWidget).

Comment: what does this line do ? 
`_MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();`

Comment: [creates the state](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) for this StatefulWidget, I suppose? (I'm new to Flutter, please pardon me if I'm missing something very basic)

Comment: I mean the state object name `_MyHomePageState()` and the name of your `RouteHome` widget do not match

Comment: `class RouteHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RouteHomeState createState() => new _RouteHomeState();
}

class _RouteHomeState extends State<RouteHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}`

Comment: Oh, that's because the name for my original widget was `MyHomePage` but I changed it. But now I've also declared the state class as `class _MyHomePageState extends State<RouteHome>`, will that be an issue?

Comment: No I just thought you had conflicted names that is all, probably it is better to show the code for the state class because I do not really understand the issue, does your build method return anything ?

Comment: It seems the issue is with `hot reload`.
I accidentally lost the connection with device and on a full restart there was no issue anymore.
Then I changed back to the original code `RouteHome extends StatelessWidget` and again hot reload throws an error - 
`The following assertion was thrown building _ModalScopeStatus(active):
I/flutter (30790): type 'RouteHome' is not a subtype of type 'StatefulWidget' of 'newWidget' where..`


**Conclusion:**
Changing RouteHome's parent causes issue on hot reload.

Comment: It is not an issue, use hot reload for minimal changes in the UI. Usually you need to do a full restart when you create new classes.

Comment: Oh, okay, will keep that in mind. 
Hot reload is still amazing!
Thanks!

Comment: @VilokanLabs Feels free to answer your own question. An edit is not enough.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hot reload is to be used for minimal UI changes only.

**Courtesy:**
"It is not an issue, use hot reload for minimal changes in the UI. Usually you need 
to do a full restart when you create new classes." – @aziza